# R- DataTable count the frequency of categorical variables and display each variable as column

Tags: r, data.table

I created a dummy data table called DT. And I am trying to calculate the sum of Capacity(numerical), Count the frequency of Code and State( Categorical) within each ID. For the end result, I want to display the sum of Capacity, frequency of A,B,C... and different State within each unique ID. Therefore, the column name will be ID,total.Cap,A,B,C... AZ,CA..

```
DT <- data.table(ID = rep(1:500,100),
            Capacity = sample(1:1000, size = 50000, replace =T),
            Code = sample(LETTERS[1:26], 50000, replace = T),
            State = rep(c("AZ","CA","PA","NY","WA","SD"), 50000))


The format of result will like the table below: 
ID total.Cap  A   B   C  ...   AZ  CA ...
1   28123    10   25  70 ...   29  ...
2   32182    20   42  50  ...  30  ...
3
```

I have tried to to use ddply, melt and dcast.. But the result does not comes out as what I thought. Could anyone give me some hints about how to structure a table looks like this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by constructing the totals, state counts, and code counts with three separate data.table statements then joining them. On states and codes, you can use `dcast` to turn it into one column per state/code with the counts within each.

```
library(data.table)

totals <- DT[, list(total.Cap = sum(Capacity)), by = "ID"]
states <- dcast(DT, ID ~ State)
codes <- dcast(DT, ID ~ Code)
```

You can then join the three tables together:

```
result <- setkey(totals, "ID")[states, ][codes, ]
```

This results in a table something like:

```
      ID total.Cap  AZ  CA  NY  PA  SD  WA  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U
  1:   1    287526 200   0   0 200   0 200 12 18 24 42 12 30 30 18  6 36 24  6 18 24 30 24  6 24 36 18 30
  2:   2    293838   0 200 200   0 200   0 18 24 42 30 30 12 24  6 24 12 48 42 18 18 42 24 24 24 12 18 24
  3:   3    279450 200   0   0 200   0 200 24 18 24  6 12 12 18 12 12 30 24 18 54 30  6 42 18 30 24 24 18
  4:   4    298200   0 200 200   0 200   0 30 30 36 30 36 24 24 18 24 18 30 30 30 24  6 30 18  6 18 18 18
  5:   5    294084 200   0   0 200   0 200 18  6 24 12 42 12 18 42 18 18 18 18 24 24 30 18 30 24  6 30 24
```

---

Note that if you have many columns like State and Code, you can do all of them at once by melting them first:

```
# replace State and Code with the categorical variables you want
melted <- melt(DT, measure.vars = c("State", "Code"))
state_codes <- dcast(melted, ID ~ value)
setkey(totals, "ID")[state_codes, ]
```

Note you still need to join with the totals, and that this will not preserve the order of columns like "states then codes" or vice versa.

Comment: Hi Patronus. Thank you so much for the quick response. Your solution works great !!  I am just curious that is there a way to do all those in one step instead of create 3 separate tables and join them together in the end?  If there are many different categorical variables in the data set, it seems like not so convince to do spread() for each variable and combine all the table together in the end. Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there were many different variables like code and state. Then yes, there's an easier version, I'll adapt my answer!

Answer (score 0):

This creates the `total.Cap`, `Code`, and `State` summary elements in three separate data tables then merges them by `ID`:

```
# Storing intermediate pieces
  total_cap <- DT[, j = list(total.Cap = sum(Capacity)), by = ID]
  code <- dcast(DT[, .N, by = c("ID", "Code")], ID ~ Code, fill = 0)
  state <- dcast(DT[, .N, by = c("ID", "State")], ID ~ State, fill = 0)

  mytable <- merge(total_cap, code, by = "ID")
  mytable <- merge(mytable, state, by = "ID")
  mytable

# As a one-liner
  mytable <- merge(
               merge(DT[, j = list(total.Cap = sum(Capacity)), by = ID],
                     dcast(DT[, .N, by = c("ID", "Code")], ID ~ Code, fill = 0),
                     by = "ID"),
               dcast(DT[, .N, by = c("ID", "State")], ID ~ State, fill = 0),
               by = "ID")
  mytable
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of @Patronus's answer - didn't see it until after I submitted mine.